# PHP para Json, criar arquivo Json

Tags: xamarin

Então, eu tenho um programa em php que criou uma conexão com o banco de dados. Agora quero saber, necessariamente eu preciso converter essas informações do php para Json para utilizar no xamarin ? E se for realmente preciso, como eu posso fazer ? Eu passei os dados para json com o json_encode(), mas não sei como faria para integrar com meu aplicativo. Podem me ajudar ?

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara. No Xamarin você faz uma requisição para esse PHP para pegar alguma informação? Se sim, tente no final da sua função em PHP adicionar o seguinte código: `exit(json_encode($variavel))`, e pegue esse retorno no seu app em Xamarin.

Comment: Estou com dificildade em criar essa "conexão" entre o PHP e o Xamarin.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest) do Xamarin para saber como consumir webservices. Acho que vai ajudar a resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Ajudou demaaiss! Valeu mesmo cara!